# Interbase XE3 Developer Edition doesn't save data

Tags: sql, database, delphi, interbase

First I tried to execute simple INSERT request using IBX and FIBPlus, the query worked out but I couldn't find the record in the database. Then I made the same request using IBExpert executed request showed in the grid but after I reconnected to the database the record wasn't there. All the transactions were commited. (Windows 7, Interbase XE3 Developer  Edition )

Code:

```
Query.Transaction.StartTransaction;
Query.SQL.Text :=
'insert into GT_AIRCRAFTSTATUS (MAINTTRACKKEY, KEY_NO, SN) values (:MAINTTRACKKEY,:KEY_NO,:SN)';
Query.ParamByName('MAINTTRACKKEY').AsInteger := 2;
Query.ParamByName('KEY_NO').AsString := 'ccc';
Query.ParamByName('SN').AsString := 'bbb';
Query.Prepare;
Query.ExecSQL;
IBSQLMonitor.OnSQL := TrackSql;
Query.Transaction.Commit;
```

IBSQLMonitor output:

```
[Application: Project6]
IBTransaction1: [Start transaction]

[Application: Project6]
Query: [Prepare] insert into GT_AIRCRAFTSTATUS (MAINTTRACKKEY, KEY_NO, SN) values (:MAINTTRACKKEY,:KEY_NO,:SN)

Plan: 

[Application: Project6]
Query: [Execute] insert into GT_AIRCRAFTSTATUS (MAINTTRACKKEY, KEY_NO, SN) values (:MAINTTRACKKEY,:KEY_NO,:SN)

MAINTTRACKKEY = 2
KEY_NO = ccc
SN = bbb

[Application: Project6]
IBTransaction1: [Commit (Hard commit)]
```

Is it a bug in the Developer Edition?

Comment: I mentioned that IBExpert didn't work out well too. This question is not about code. The code is correct.

Comment: Sorry, but we can't debug what we can't see. If you suspect a bug in Interbase, contact Embarcadero and open a report in [Quality Central](http://qc.embarcadero.com). Note that in order for them to open the bug, you'll have to provide steps to demonstrate and reproduce the problem, so you'll have to do much better in writing your bug report than you have in writing your question here. (Hopefully, you're more willing to participate with them than you have with me; I am, after all, asking for the same thing and you seem unwilling to provide it.)

Comment: "All the transactions were commited."  All? Even the ones by your Delphi app?

Comment: Yes, all the transactions and in Delphi app too. I worked before with Firebird/Interbases databases but never encountered such a problems.

Comment: I removed the Firebird tag, your question explicitly mentions you use Interbase

Answer (score 0):

The table was a temporary table. When I last used Interbase/Firbird temporary tables weren't supported by these servers.